# How to increase number of threads directly through CSV file

Tags: multithreading, jmeter, threadgroup

I have a test plan and that have around 50 threads(individually) in j-meter and for each thread, I want to increase my thread count depending upon the load we trigger.

So sometimes its 10 sometime it's 20 etc and I have CSV file config through which I pass the parameters like UN and Pass.

So every time I run I have to update the thread count of an individual thread manually. 
So is there any way I can do it by.CSV file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use "jp@gc - Variables From CSV File" plugin to get the threads and pass it to the thread group.
Please check below:-
[image]
[image]
[image]

Hope this helps.